# Case class design in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

In the Java world while writing the data access layer (for CRUD) and the model layer, I have done something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<N extends AbstractModel>{
        protected Class<N> persistentClass;
        public N findById(String id){

                return (N)mongoOperation.findById(id, persistentClass,persistentClass.getSimpleName());

        }
}

class FlightDao extends AbstractDao<Flight>
class AirlineDaoImpl extends AbstractMongoDao<Airline>
```

Where `Flight extends AbstractModel` and ,`Airline extended AbstractModel`

Now calling the findById was as trivial as

```
Flight flight = flightDao.findById("FlightId1");
```

I feel this was a decent way of doing things because it kept my code DRY. And most of the model objects needed the same CRUD methods.

Now coming to Scala, Play framework 2, anorm, I would like to know what is the right way of doing something such as this.

I read that model classes should be case classes but then that prevents us from inheritance. And moreover the data access definitions were given in the companion objects. This is what I have at the moment.

```
case class Airline(id:Pk[Long]=NotAssigned,name:String)
case class Flight(id:Pk[Long]=NotAssigned,code:String,airlineId:Long,date:DateTime)

object Flight{
    def getById(id:Long):Option[Flight] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
       SQL(
        """
          select * from flight        
          where flight.id =  {id}
        """
      ).on(
        'id -> id       
      ).as(Flight.simple.singleOpt)
    } 

  }
}

object Airline{
    def getById(id:Long):Option[Airline] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
       SQL(
        """
          select * from airline        
          where airline.id =  {id}
        """
      ).on(
        'id -> id       
      ).as(Airline.simple.singleOpt)
    } 

  }
}
```

I'm **certain** there must be a better way to do this.  I would love to know how I could write neat / clean Scala code for this. Any pointers, design patterns and feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing prevent your case classes from using inheritance at all. What you can't do is extend case classes. Example https://gist.github.com/fedesilva/d9e636695484d8eaddea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that in addition to the stated Java -> Scala OO question, that you may also be wondering about a good way to "organize" Models/DAOs/Controllers in Play 2. So I will incorporate that in my answer.

I would have asked in a comment, but I don't seem to have the rep yet...

A few notes before we get into an answer:

- fedesilvia is correct, that case classes can extend traits and/or classes.
- Model classes generally should be case classes. They're a nice, easy-to-use construct that provides your "equals" method, "toString" method, and "hashcode" method. Also, many libraries have provided great mechanisms for working with case classes for a variety of purposes. Not to mention matching, immutable by default, etc...

Let's take a look at how to organize this from top to bottom.

### Controllers

As you know, Play's Router sends requests in from the HTTP client to your Controller. It is my opinion that the Controllers then have 3 *core* responsibilities:

1. Deserialize the request.
2. Serialize the response.
3. Handle any errors appropriately.

Missing between responsibilities 1 and 2, is the actual "handling" of the request. For a CRUD app, this could be where your DAOs come in.

### DAOs

In my application, DAOs are *Objects* that extend a **MongoDAO** trait. The trait "knows" how to interact the the database drivers (get a connection), and supplies basic utilities. For instance:

```
/** Basic DAO Behavior for MongoDB documents. */
trait MongoDao {
  /** Name of the MongoDB Collection. */
  protected def colName: String

  /** Returns the default database. */
  protected def db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db

  /** The actual collection used by the DAO. */
  protected def col: JSONCollection =
    db.collection[JSONCollection](colName)

  /** Returns the first result, if any, for the given query. */
  def findOne[DOC](q: JsObject)(implicit reads: Reads[DOC]) =
    col.find(q).cursor[DOC].headOption

  ...
```

I also have an *abstract class* that extends **MongoDAO** called, "AssetDAO". **AssetDao** provides 90% to 100% of the DAO implementation for 13 of the Models in my App. Here is it's type:

```
/** Common DAO behavior for all Assets. */
abstract class AssetDao[A <: AssetModel]
  (override val colName: String)(implicit format: Format[A])
extends MongoDao with ModulePermissions {
```

The DAO implementations can look like this:

```
object ArchetypeDao extends AssetDao[Archetype]("archetypes")
```

But most of them also have a couple methods that are all their own. Usually when I need to make use of Model specific properties in a query.

### Model Companion Objects

Given the libraries that I'm using (notably *play.api.lib.json*), I find it best to put (de-)serialization code in the Companion Objects. For instance:

```
object Archetype {
  /** Converts Archetype to/from its MongoDB representation */
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Archetype]

  /** Reads that are used for both Create and Update. */
  val coreReads = (
    (__ \ "name"   ).json.pickBranch(smlReqStr) and
    (__ \ "summary").json.pickBranch(medReqStr) and

    ((__ \ "description").json.pickBranch(fullText) or emptyObj)
  ) reduce
}
```

As you can see, the *Companion Object* contains all of the information it needs to (de-)serialize the *case class* to/from its MongoDB representation; and to/from its "client" representation. So the *DAO* ends up using the **Json.format** and the *Controller* uses the JSON Transformers.

### Models

In this setup, all *Models* are simple *case classes* that represent *persisted* data. For instance:

```
case class Archetype (
  _id:         BSONObjectID,
  module_id:   BSONObjectID,
  doc_meta:    DocMeta,
  name:        String,
  summary:     String,
  description: Option[String]
) extends AssetModel
```

And here is the **AssetModel** trait that **Archetype** implements:

```
/** Describes some common behavior of asset types */
trait AssetModel {
  def _id:       BSONObjectID
  def module_id: BSONObjectID
  def doc_meta:  DocMeta
}
```

You may have noticed earlier that **Archetype.coreReads** doesn't reference all the fields the model has. That's because the "AssetControllers" are taking care of the rest of the fields for every **AssetModel**. Implementing **AssetModel** here is what makes that work.

To do it again, I might have the **AssetModel** *Companion Objects* extend a trait that provides the common field (de)serialization.

## Conclusion

Hopefully, this answer has provided you with:

1. A better understanding of using OO in Scala.
2. Some ideas for organizing your Play App to write DRY code.

Comment: Now THAT's an answer! Awesome, keep it up! Don't feel pressured to post very long answers that cover everything though, posting a partial review is perfectly fine ;)

Comment: Github or Gist with examples?